# SBT terminates silently when Git repository for build plugin can't be downloaded

Tags: sbt

SBT is *silently* failing when it can't download a plugin via SSH from a Git repository.

This is the output of SBT when it's trying to download the repository:

```
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("ssh://git@repository.com/plugin.git"), "plugin")...
# (nothing after that line)
```

And it just terminates after that with no explanation. This is very likely a bug with SBT's downloading of plugins via SSH from a Git repository.

When downloading the plugin succeeds, this line is printed:

```
[info] Done updating.
```

So for some reason, SBT isn't stating what's wrong, even when executed like this:

```
sbt -Xdebug test
```

Here are the relevant configuration files:

```
# project/build-properties
sbt.version=1.1.5

# project/plugins.sbt
lazy val buildPlugin = RootProject(uri("ssh://git@repository.com/plugin.git"))
lazy val root        = (project in file(".")).dependsOn(buildPlugin)
```

**Questions:**

**1. How can I get SBT to print more debugging information?**

**2. Where in the SBT code could I fix this bug?**

**3. How can I build and use my own version of SBT?**

Comment: Regarding questions 2 and 3, check the official [contributing guide](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.x/CONTRIBUTING.md)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How can I get SBT to print more debugging information?

Using the latest launching script available from https://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html (1.2.1 as of August, 2018), you can run:

```
$ sbt -debug
```

> 2. Where in the SBT code could I fix this bug?

See my answer here https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1120#issuecomment-415553592:

Here are some of the relevant code:

- `Load.builtinLoader` - https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.2.1/main/src/main/scala/sbt/internal/Load.scala#L480-L488
- `RetrieveUnit` - https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.2.1/main/src/main/scala/sbt/internal/RetrieveUnit.scala
- `Resolvers.git` - https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.2.1/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Resolvers.scala#L82-L101
- `Resolvers.creates` - https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.2.1/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Resolvers.scala#L145-L155

```scala
  val git: Resolver = (info: ResolveInfo) => {
    val uri = info.uri.withoutMarkerScheme
    val localCopy = uniqueSubdirectoryFor(uri.copy(scheme = "git"), in = info.staging)
    val from = uri.withoutFragment.toASCIIString

    if (uri.hasFragment) {
      val branch = uri.getFragment
      Some { () =>
        creates(localCopy) {
          run("git", "clone", from, localCopy.getAbsolutePath)
          run(Some(localCopy), "git", "checkout", "-q", branch)
        }
      }
    } else
      Some { () =>
        creates(localCopy) {
          run("git", "clone", "--depth", "1", from, localCopy.getAbsolutePath)
        }
      }
  }

....

  def creates(file: File)(f: => Unit) = {
    if (!file.exists)
      try {
        f
      } catch {
        case NonFatal(e) =>
          IO.delete(file)
          throw e
      }
    file
  }
```

> 3. How can I build and use my own version of SBT?

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/1.x/CONTRIBUTING.md#build-from-source

For this, you just need sbt/sbt, and `publishLocal`.